# Making Photo Grid with Different size images

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Ok, may be its really simple. but, I can't figure it out how to do it. What I want is to query one table and show results in two divs on the page. What I mean is that I have some html like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small">
      //
    </div>
    <div class="large">
      //
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      //
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      //
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      //
    </div>
    <div class="large">
      //
    </div>
</div>
```

and the query like this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cars_cat = ? ORDER BY car_id DESC");
$stmt->execute(array($cat_id));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($data as $row)  {

}
```

The database table is simple table with `id, name, image, cars_cat`.

UPDATE:
This is the structure of the gallery

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- First Column -->

       <div class="small">

       </div>  

       <div class="large">

       </div>  

       <div class="small">

       </div>

       <div class="small">

       </div>
  </div> <!-- End First Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- Second Column -->
       <div class="small">

       </div>

       <div class="small">

       </div>

       <div class="large">

       </div>

       <div class="small">

       </div>
  </div> <!-- End Second Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 nopadding"> <!-- Third Column -->

       <div class="large">

       </div>

       <div class="small">

       </div>

       <div class="large">
            //
       </div>

  </div> <!-- End Third Column -->
```

Comment: You want the same data in both the divs ?

Comment: Not the same. Load all data ordered by id from database. Let me edit a little the question because they are few small and 2-3 large divs.

Comment: Edited. They are like this. That's why I can't figured how can be made. ID-1 in first small div.. ID-2 in next div and so on.

Comment: This is weird. How can you be sure that there would be exactly the same amount of divs to the number of rows returned from the db.

Comment: use ajax to get data and update the result in number of div.

Comment: It's a structure of the gallery template. In the large div's are vertical images in small divs are horizontal.

Comment: @PrerakSola, I don't need them to be the same amount. I mean it will have LIMIT X and pagination. I just need to know how I can load divs on this kind of html structure.

Comment: Also I've been thinking for some query every nth row from database to be in large box for example.. but they are not on the same position after small box. First large box is second position. Second large box is 7th.. Third large box is 9th..

Comment: you could help by supplying example data for your query, and then show how you'd LIKE it to appear in the divs

Comment: It is just this that I wrote in my question. Generally in divs I will show only the image `<img ... >`. The query in one page is `select * from cars`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<style>
    .row {
        -webkit-column-width:400px;
        -moz-column-width:400px;
        column-width:400px;
        -webkit-column-gap:5px;
        -moz-column-gap:5px;
        column-gap:5px;
    }
    .small-box{
        display:inline-block; 
        margin:0 0 5px 0;
        padding:10px;
        color:white;
    }
    .img-responsive{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
    }
</style>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="small-box">
                    <img src="http://aneemals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/photos-of-animals-that-know-what-love-is-3.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="small-box">
                    <img src="http://www.softstuffcreations.com/refresh/data/zoom_image/1772-PandaBear_resized.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>

                <div class="small-box">
                    <img src="http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/35600000/wild-animals-animals-of-the-world-35665506-800-533.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="small-box">
                    <img src="http://nice-animals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/facts-of-love-between-animals-08.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="small-box">
                    <img src="http://www.kenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Mt-Kenya-Animals.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="small-box">
                    <img src="http://www.softstuffcreations.com/refresh/data/zoom_image/1772-PandaBear_resized.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="small-box">
                    <img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2012/364/4/3/animals___lion_9_by_moonsongstock-d5pr9za.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Means basically what you need to update is to update code this way

```
    <div class="row">
   <?php
      foreach($data as $row)  {     
        echo '<div class="small-box"> your image </div>';         
 }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Well thank's for the answer. I will try to rewrite that gallery. It si bootstrap based template and when I edit rows like your I need to put 100% width but then I get only small images.

Comment: You can add one more div inside row and add css rules to that div....giving width 100% will not work you have to specify width in pixel...that will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
   <?php
      foreach($data as $row)  {
         if($row->div_type == 0){
            echo '<div class="small"> your data </div>';
         }else{
            echo '<div class="large"> your data </div>';
         }
      }
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this mean that I need to add another row into database table where I will save `small` or `large` ?

Comment: what data cars_cat column having??

Comment: Integer .. this is the ID of the category of cars.. based on this I show all cars from the category.

Comment: `small, small, small,small, small, LARGE, small, LARGE, small, LARGE` this is how they are displayed on the page

Comment: You may add new column to database specifying when you want small div and large div.....lets say div_type, when its set to 0 you will display small div and when its set to 1 you will display large div

Comment: But you also gave me good idea. May be is better to have one row `small` or `large` in the table and based of this will load images.. can you write simple example `if else` of this?

Comment: Yes like this will work I guess but there is another problem whit the HTML part that I just saw while trying to get this to work. They are in three columns. I've updated my question how are they. Is it possible to happen with this kind of structure?

Comment: when you want to display first,second and third column.....Please update your question...

Comment: All at the time.. I mean this is gallery. They are like this. When page is loaded should load this columns with images from the table. But I can't understand how to implement this into the snipped you gave..

Comment: It's exact like this gallery - https://jsfiddle.net/uLwhuvyq/2/ .. Resize a little the pane with images to see result

Comment: Rather than having three columns just have one column and try to manage with it...

Comment: This will help you....[link](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/nX9NT/1/embedded/result%2Chtml%2Ccss/)